# Why is my vim slow when editing PHP files?

Tags: php, performance, vim

if I edit php file, Vim gets so slow... when I scroll text in normal mode or if I write in insert mode.

However my files aren't nothing special: until 90 characters per line, about 150 lines per file.

But Vim is slow only if I edit **php** file. When editing javascript with up to 700 lines and all plugins enabled, Vim runs fine (ps: for javascript I use much more performance demanding plugins).

In php files I do not get lags after I disable syntax highlighting (syntax off).
However, what's interesting **Vim also runs fast with syntax highlighting enabled when I run Vim with flag:**

> --noplugin

With that known, I tried delete all my custom installed plugins and run Vim without --noplugin flag. - Unfortunately, vim still lagging when editing php files.

One important fact: It does not matter what kind of syntax highlighting I use. For all colorschemes behavior is same as described above.

I tried setting up these options (without change):

```
set nocursorcolumn
set nocursorline
syntax sync minlines=256
```

So, question is, what can I do for having vim which run without lags while editing php files?
I use Windows.

Comment: I said that I tried delete all my plugins but without any change...

Comment: Whoops sorry missed that.

Comment: Is this vim 7.4? It came with a new regex engine and a couple of syntax files started behaving quite poorly. Try `set regexpengine=1` to force the old regex engine.

Comment: It does not help. But thanks for try.
Vim version: 7.4 64bit

Comment: Removing plugins manually and doing --noplugin should work similarly. Can you try running :scriptnames in both and see if there are any differences?

Comment: Ok, this helped me! Thank you! I feel a little stupid. There was one plugin that I did not delete. It was placed in global vimfiles folder in users directory. I haven't used this folder. Plugin (for highlighting current line) was there from another vim version that I used and it even didn't work with current vim version. p.s:Fortunately, nowadays I use pathogen.

Answer (score 2):

```
let g:loaded_matchparen = 1
```

At the top of my .vimrc solved the problem for me. This disabled the bundled plugin and my scrolling up and down and general speed of navigation improved substantially.